# Unbalanced Anova

Tags: regression, anova

I have an unbalanced 2 by 3 between-subjects ANOVA that I am doing as a regression. I'm using Helmert coefficients to code A and B, and the products of these to code the AB interaction. Because the design is not balanced the five coefficient vectors are not orthogonal.

When I compute in **separate regressions** the sum of squares for A (one vector), B (two vectors), and  AB (two vectors) I get SSA, SSB, and SSAB. However, the sum of these (SSA+SSB+SSAB) is less then the SS I get when all five vectors are entered simultaneously (SSALL).

I don't understand this. Because the five vectors are not orthogonal I expected (SSA+SSB+SSAB) to be greater than SSALL. Can you tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: My best guess is that you're dealing with a case of suppression. When adding the predictors sequentially you may find that the change in R2 is greater than the zero-order correlation of the vector with y.

Comment: You're right! One of the interaction vectors (x1) correlates weakly with y (r = -.228, r^2 = .052) and much more strongly with one of the other vectors.  When x1 is added to the model (after the other 4 have were introduced) the R2-change is .2!! Classic case of suppression, I guess.